# Locate element using Capybara in RSPEC

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

> How can get or locate the element for uploading image when using
>   bootstrap upload file.

**Here is my html for upload.**

```
<input id="input-id" name="user[image]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" data-show-preview="false" data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true" />
```

**Here is the rendered html in browser:**

```
<span class="file-input file-input-new">
<div class="kv-upload-progress hide"></div>
<div class="input-group ">
   <div tabindex="-1" class="form-control file-caption  kv-fileinput-caption">
   <span class="file-caption-ellipsis">…</span>
   <div class="file-caption-name"></div>
</div>
   <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="button" title="Clear selected files" class="btn btn-default fileinput-remove fileinput-remove-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Remove</button>
       <button type="button" title="Abort ongoing upload" class="hide btn btn-default fileinput-cancel fileinput-cancel-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Cancel</button>

       <div class="btn btn-primary btn-file"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> &nbsp;Browse … <input id="input-id" name="user[image]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" data-show-preview="false" data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</span>
```

**Here is my Capybara code locating and passing image:**

```
attach_file('what_here', Rails.root + 'public/sample.jpg')
```

I tried different value for **what_here** above, but unfortunately i got error:

```
Failure/Error: attach_file('file-caption', Rails.root + 'public/sample.jpg')

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find file field "file-caption(tried diff. selector here)"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is failing because the file input is not visible on the page.  This is common with file inputs since they're often hidden to allow for other srylable elements to be used. To test them you need to use `execute_script` to adjust the CSS of the element so it becomes visible on the page and can then call attach_file on it.  The CSS you need to add to the element depends on how it's being hidden, opacity, zindex, position, etc. Once you've made it visible then you can do

```
attach_file('input-id', ...)
```

Comment: Hi @Tom , I'm very new to rspec testing. Just started studying it yesterday. Please provide sample code on how to use/do it with your suggestion.

Comment: As I stated it depends on how the element is being hidden, for instance if it has an opacity of 0 (and you're using jquery) you could do something like `page.execute_script("$('selector to file input').css('opacity', 1)")`